# Displaying categories without repeating each that has posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have **categories** table:

```
cat_id
cat_name
```

Than categories - posts relationship table **cat_rel**:

```
cat_rel_id
cat_id
post_id
```

And **posts** table:

```
post_id
post_title
post_content
```

Now I have data in all these tables, I need to pull out categories without to repeat those that have more than 1 post. I get somehow category repeated if it has more than 1 post, eg. categories like:

php, python, c++, java, ruby

if I have 2 posts under PHP, I will get:

php
python
php
java

and this is the query I run:

```
SELECT categories.cat_name, cat_rel.post_id 
FROM categories 
LEFT JOIN cat_rel ON cat_rel.cat_ID = categories.cat_ID
```

Any help about making those categories not to repeat, would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DISTINCT

Have a look here:
[SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This would list the categories with more than one post:

```
SELECT  categories.cat_name as Category
,       count(distinct cat_rel.post_id) as PostCount
FROM    categories 
LEFT JOIN cat_rel 
ON      cat_rel.cat_ID = categories.cat_ID
GROUP BY categories.cat_name
HAVING  count(distinct cat_rel.post_id) > 1
```

Comment: The OP wants to pull out all categories without to repeat those that have more than 1 post, not to pull out all categories with more than one post.

Comment: @MGA: then why is he joining to `cat_rel` at all?  Just `select cat_name from categories` would pull out all categories.

Comment: I don't know, but this is what he said in his question, any way I think you should just remove `HAVING  count(distinct cat_rel.post_id) > 1` from your query.

Comment: lol @Andomar I just took a look at code and I see that simple `select cat_name from categories` would work, I have no idea why I joined this table here, I'm an idiot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT categories.cat_name, cat_rel.post_id 
FROM categories 
LEFT JOIN cat_rel ON cat_rel.cat_ID = categories.cat_ID
```

Comment: `distinct` applies to all columns, so `distinct cat_name, post_id` would still repeat the category